# 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'support_vectors_'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm, gridsearchcv

I am trying to find best parameters using GridSearch and then also find out support vectors using the best parameters.

Here is the code:

```
tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.1,1, 10, 100, 1000],
                     'decision_function_shape':["ovo"]}]
clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(), tuned_parameters, cv=5)
clf.fit(X, Y)
print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
print()
print(clf.best_params_)
# Predicting on the unseen test data
predicted_test = clf.predict(X_test)

# Calculating Accuracy on test data
accuracy_test=accuracy_score(Yt, predicted_test)
support_vec=clf.support_vectors_
print(support_vec)
```

Error:

```
 AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'support_vectors_'
```

sklearn 0.21.2

How to fix this issue?

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using?

Comment: sklearn 0.21.2  version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `GridSearchCV` *isn't* `SVC`, rather it *contains* a `SVC` object. This is why it doesn't have `support_vectors_` attribute, and throws error.

To access the `SVC` inside `GridSearchCV`, use its `best_estimator_` attribute. So instead of

```
clf.support_vectors_
```

Call:

```
clf.best_estimator_.support_vectors_
```

Just to be on the safe side, include `refit=True` while instantiating `GridSearchCV`.